# Always position Div Element in center of second Div that is Resizable and Draggable

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, centering, resizable

I've tried a few different jQuery centering plugins but can't seem to figure this out. Basically I have three DIVs positioned on top of each other like shown:

----- (DIV 1 - Draggable Element that also drags DIV 3)

------- (DIV 2 - Contains a Transparent Image - Stays Stationary)

--------- (DIV 3 - Contains Image that Drags with DIV 1 but is also Resizable and can Rotate)

So basically DIV1 contains an image (move icon) that when dragged moves DIV3 and I need the icon in DIV1 to always be in the center of DIV3 regardless of where (3) is moved or resized or rotated. I would really appreciate any help, can't seem to get anything to work properly.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBNDf/1/

Thanks,

Sean

```
                            <h1>Preview</h1>
                            <br>
                            <!-- Zoom Slider -->
                            <div id="zoomslider" style="float:left; width:55px; height:405px;">
                                    <div id="slider-vertical" style="height:100%; margin: auto auto;"></div>
                            </div>

                            <!--- Preview Container -->
                            <div id="previewcontainer" style="float:left; width:485px; height:405px;">

                                <div id="drag-overlay"></div>

                                <div id="background-overlay">
                                </div>  

                                    <!-- Loaded Face Image  -->
                                    <div id="loaded-image" class="preview ui-widget-content ui-draggable"></div>

                            </div>

                                <!-- Clear Fix -->
                                <div id="blank" style="float:left; width:55px; height:55px;"></div>

                            <!-- Rotate Slider -->
                            <div id="rotateslider" style="float:left; width:485px; height:55px;">
                                <br>
                                    <div id="slider" style="width:100%; margin: auto auto;"></div>
                            </div>                                  


                            <script>
                                //make resizable and rotate via slider
                                //make draggable
                                //get position of loaded-image
                                $("#drag-overlay").multiDraggable({ group: [$("#drag-overlay"),$(".preview") ]});

                                $("#slider-vertical").slider({
                                    orientation: "vertical",
                                    value: 50,
                                    max: 500,
                                    min: 100,
                                    slide: function(event, ui) {
                                        $( ".preview" ).width(ui.value);
                                        $( ".preview" ).height(ui.value);
                                 }
                                });

                                $("#slider").slider({
                                  min: 0, // degrees
                                  max: 360, // degrees
                                  slide: function(e, ui) {
                                    $('.preview').jangle(ui.value);
                                  },
                                  stop: function(e, ui) { // in case you out slide the slider
                                    $('.preview').jangle(ui.value);
                                  }
                                });

                                //center drag element onto loaded-image
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your question, maybe a `jsfiddle` would do the trick?

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for your time. http://jsfiddle.net/EBNDf/1/
So I want to position the cursor icon in the middle of the loaded-image div.

Comment: I don't know much about mootools, but you should be able to position the element after dragging the box with some sort of callback... Your fiddle says mootools but are you using jQuery? I can't find any documentation regarding `multiDraggable`

Comment: Jeff the fiddle accidentally had mootools selected, jQuery was what was used in the resources. Thanks for your help, believe I got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed up the math a little bit to not depend on the original css positioning, and instead be completely dynamic and the actual element dimensions.

Check out the code below for a completely dynamic example of what I'm talking about. I've used $drag_overlay to "optimize" your selection, so the dom doesn't do repetitive document.getElementByIds. Being that it's a direct ID, the optimization won't prove any incredible performance increases, but a little efficiency can go a long way :) It does however have a more substantial effect on the $('.preview') selector :)

```
var $drag_overlay = $('#drag-overlay'),
    $preview = $('.preview');

$drag_overlay.css({
    top : $preview.height() / 2 - $drag_overlay.height() / 4,
    left : $preview.width() / 2 - $drag_overlay.width() / 4   
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work, if anyone needs it you can view the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EBNDf/12/

Open to better suggestions as well.